# Defining Kendo UI Grid Column Templates with a Function that returns a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to create a Kendo UI for jQuery column which uses a function to determine the template. Essentially the data I am receiving from the backend gives me a number, and I need to match up that number to the corresponding entry in another database table. Once the match is found, I need to set the column template to show that entry.

```
template: function (e) {
    countryData.forEach(function (country) {
        let countryDesc;
        if (country.countryCode == e.countryCode) {
             countryDesc = country.description;
             return countryDesc;
         }
     })
 }
```

This is the function that I have written. `countryData` is an array of JSON objects containing a list of countries with codes, I am matching that code up with `e.countryCode` to get the correct country. This is then assigned to countryDesc, and returned.

When ran, the columns are just displayed as 'undefined'. I'm confused as to why this isn't working, as if I do this for example: `template: "foo"`, the column would display `foo`. Surely all i'm doing is returning a string, so this should work?

Comment: try to log country countryData content. Also, share your kendo grid definition code. If you add a snippet with some dummy data It would be easier to identify the problem

Answer (score 0):

So after trying loads of things, replacing the `.forEach` with a plain `for` fixed this issue.

```
template: function (e) {
    let country;
    for (i = 0; i < countryData.length; i++) {
        if (countryData[i].countryCode == e.countryCode) {
           country = countryData[i].description;
    }
    return country;
}
```